# Java native methods. Public vs. private

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Assume that we need to implement some java method in native code and expose it to user. We know that all work is done by native side, i.e. the only responsibility of java code is to pass user-supplied arguments to native code and return result back. According to this, java layer may be implemented in two ways:

- By using of native methods that are directly exposed to user:

  ```
  public native Object doSmth(Object arg0, Object arg1);
  ```
- By using of thin public wrapper around private native method:

  ```
  public Object doSmth(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
      return nativeDoSmth(arg0, arg1);
  }

  private native Object nativeDoSmth(Object arg0, Object arg1);
  ```

I've seen both approaches in real projects and even both former and latter in the same project.

So, my question is: does any of mentioned alternatives have some technical or performance or maintainability advantages, that should encourage to use only one variant. Or maybe it is all just a matter of taste?

Comment: A `public` method is part of the objects API. A `native` method is an implementation decision. Implementation details should not be visible to the public API. Option 2 hides implementation from API.

Comment: You'll find option 2 used exclusively in the JDK, not option 1. I think it's a good idea, it gives you another degree of freedom when designing & maintaining your JNI layer.

Comment: Your question assumes that the signatures are the same. This is often not the case because what's natural for the class's  API can be a lot of work in JNI code. In many cases, it is simpler to transform inputs and outputs using Java to data types that are easier to work with in JNI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, my question is: does any of mentioned alternatives have some
>   technical or performance or maintainability advantages, that should
>   encourage to use only one variant.

Maintainability advantage is the key here. As stated in the comments, the object exposes its behavior. How it is implemented is not the user's business. This gives you more flexibility.

Suppose that in the future (see: *maintainability*) you find that you want/need to adjust the method such that it does something before and/or after the native call. In the first approach, you will need to deprecate the method and create a new one. In the second second approach, you just add whatever you need in the method and the user doesn't care.

As for performance, in theory, the first approach is faster because it's 1 less call. In practice, it's completely negligible.

Comment: There is no need to deprecate the method, as you can simply change from the first variant to the second without any client code ever noticing. So there is no need to use the second before that is really needed. Of course, it would require recompiling the native code, but this should be in your control.

Comment: @Holger I don't understand. In the first approach you want to make the changes in the native code? The same changes you would have made in the Java side if you were using the second approach?

Comment: No. When there is a need to decorate the method on the Java side, you can just change variant 1 to variant 2, getting all benefits of the second variant. Since the name of the `native` method differs in both variants, the native code’s name needs to be adapted, or a delegate with the new name created. In either case, the native code would need to be recompiled, but not significantly changed.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's mostly a personal style choice. If you consider the following code:

rattias-macbookpro:tst rattias$ diff Test1.cl Test1.class 
rattias-macbookpro:tst rattias$ vi Test1.java

```
public class Test1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test2 t = new Test2();
    t.m();
  }
}

public class Test2 {
  public native void m();
}
```

Compiling this produces a `Test1.class` which is identical to the one produced when `Test2` is defined as follows:

```
public class Test2 {
  public void m() {
  }
}
```

This means that you could change the implementation to be native, pure java, a pure java wrapper to a native private method, at any point in time without affecting the users. There may be a question to whether an entire public API function needs to be native, vs. just a portion of the computation, but again that can be changed at any point.